# Why does terminal tell me to change main to string

Tags: java

This is the program I'm trying to run

```
public class PracticeTwo {
    public static void main(int[] args){
        int[] lower = {-4,-3,-7};
        for(int i=0; i<0; i++){
            int[] greater = {5,2,6};
            for(int j=0; j>0; j++){
                if(greater.length>0);
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(j) + " is greater than 0");
                if(lower.length<0);
                System.out.println(Integer.toString(i) + " is lower than 0");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is no compiling issues but when i try to run it returns this:

```
Error: Main method not found in class PracticeTwo, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

Comment: `int[] != String[]`... This is a simple typo

Comment: The signature of the main method must be `public static void main(String[] args)` exactly as the error message explains.

Comment: `There is no compiling issues but when i try to run it returns this:`

Correct, the syntax is correct (generally) so there is no compilation error.  This is a runtime error since the `main` method in java is special and important when running any Java application and requires a specific signature.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the declaration of your `main` method, as the error description reads, it should be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Pay close attention to the errors and warnings, they exist for a reason.

Comment: i understand that but when i change that i am unable to use "int"

Comment: You can't type a non-string on the command line anyway (123 is a string of 3 characters in this context) - and the args array comes from the command line.  You'll have to parse the strings into ints.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be listed:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Hello World!");

}
```

Anything inside this method will run when you run the program.